# Difference, Binary vs multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is there any difference in the implementation between binary and multi-class classification?

Comment: ps. For the haters who down-voted me at least write why i was wrong and why i asked a stupid question or not so smart question.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly -- a binary classifier does not automatically help in performing multi-class classification since "multi" might be > 2.

A standard technique to fake N-class with a binary classifier is to build N binary classifiers for each of the labels and then see which of the N binary classifiers is most confident in its class, and choose that. So, that much at least is different in this case.

There are also algorithms that more directly support multi-class, like random decision forests. Since 2 is a special case of multi, no, there would be no difference in applying RDF to a binary vs multi-class problem.